# How to use JQuery to inject a variable into a javascript function's parameters?

Tags: jquery

Here's my  tag:

```
<div class="ContentBlock">
    <a href="javascript:setActiveCookie('12345',7)"><img src="/images/blah.gif"></a>
</div>
```

Rather than hard-coding that value of '12345', I'd like to edit this dynamically from a javascript function and inject a variable parameter there instead.

Any ideas how to do this?

Here's some JQuery where I'd like to do this.  Basically, I am building 10 dynamic rows, each will have the above  tag and each needs to use its own "ID" as a parameter in that 's call to 'setActiveCookie'.  (The ID is used to set a cookie value, FWIW).  Below, I've got a CLONE and have already swapped JSON stringify'd values into the dynamically-generated HTML.   I just need to inject this ID into the  function call.  Any help is appreciated!!

```
$.each( val, function( key2, value ) {
    ///inject key2 and value into already-cloned JS object here.  This already is working.
    if ( key2 == 'storeId' ) {
        var ID = ( JSON.stringify( value ) );
        ///Shove this ID into the <a> tag here???
    }
} );
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was...                                               store.find('a#'+key2).attr('id','ID_'+value);

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 `data-` attrbute:

Set values:

```
$('#X').data('value1',12345)
$('#X').data('value2',7)
```

HTML

```
<a id="X" href="javascript:setActiveCookie(this)"><img src="/images/blah.gif"></a>
```

Get values:

```
function setActiveCookie(element) {
      var value1 = $(element).data('value1')
      var value2 = $(element).data('value2')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no a JavaScript guy, but I believe you should be able to define a map of row # to this ID, like `id[row] = 12345`.  And then in your JQuery function, just reassign the value in that map: `id[row] = ID`.  In the anchor tag, just have `<a href="javascript:setActiveCookie(id[row], row)>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the `href` attribute, use `javascript:void(0);` and then set the click event in jQuery:

```
<a id="Link1" href="javascript:void(0);">Link Text or Image</a>
```

javascript:

```
  $.each(val,function(key2,value){

              ///inject key2 and value into already-cloned JS object here.  This already is working.
              if (key2=='storeId' ){
                  $("#Link1").click(function() {
                      setActiveCookie(value, 7);
                  });
              }

          });
```

Comment: that's not working for some reason.  I like the approach though.